# Unable to install v0.11.0 tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow

I am having issues with installing the v0.11.0 version of tensorflow-gpu. My code works on tensorflow==0.11.0 but really slow. I had a tensorflow-gpu==0.11.0 but i had lost it due to an upgrade. The `pip` repository doesn't have a v0.11 anymore and starts with v0.12 only. I got the v0.11 wheel from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#using-pip). I am able to install tensorflow==0.11.0 using the wheel at `export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

but I am unable to install the GPU version of tensorflow-gpu==0.11.0 using the corresponding link at `export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

The link looks same to me with just the folder different from `gpu/` and `cpu/`. Upon using the link for GPU, it installs `tensorflow==0.11.0` and not `tensorflow-gpu=0.11.0`. Where can I find a `tensorflow-gpu==0.11.0` wheel?

Comment: Is it possible to move to tensorflow 1.0?  I expect that has better support.

Comment: Not really, i am facing a lot more issues for my code, keeps throwing a `scope` error which I am unable to understand

Comment: I would also second the move to 1.0 or greater. There really isn't much reason to not upgrade unless you have some seriously complex code that won't migrate or you're in a huge production environment that you can't easily upgrade.